# Removing unused profiles from Windows network connections

Tags: windows-7, connection

Can't figure this one out. When you connect to a wireless network (like an ad-hoc), it'll create a `networkname 1` connection. After something changes, it makes a `networkname 2` connection. And this goes on and on. Now I'm at connection ~23, at the home connection I'm at ~2 and ~5.

Is there a way to clean these out? Couldn't find where Win stores such profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open "Network and Sharing Centre".
- Under "View your active networks" click the icon beside the network (park bench, work, home icon).
- Click "Merge or delete network locations"

Comment: Awesomeness. Thank you. :) (Oh my god what a huge list...)